# Mobile Chrome doesn't register click after scrolling on "touch-action: none" area

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, scroll, click

I currently have the issue where I have a `div` with `touch-action: none`. The user drags/scrolls on this `div`, then he can interact with UI (links/buttons) outside of this `div`.

**The issue**: If the user scrolls on the `div` and then immediately interacts with UI outside of it, then it won't register any interactions. Sometimes it helps if I wait a couple of seconds, other times the only fix is to tap twice.

This only happens on **Mobile Chrome**. Firefox on a mobile, for example, does not have this issue.

**Does someone know why this happens, and how I could circumvent this issue?**

If you have such a mobile phone and run Chrome, you can see it in action here: https://codepen.io/BigBoomer/pen/BaZwgRZ

Comment: i don't know, but same like me. i think it's Mobile Chrome Bug, i'am using IOS Chrome Mobile